# Usage of "would expect / would have expected"

Tags: word-usage, difference, modal-verbs

Consider:

> 1. The conclusion is contrary to what you expected.
> 2. The conclusion is contrary to what you would expect.
> 3. The conclusion is contrary to what you would have expected.
> 4. Who would have expected such a counterintuitive conclusion?

In coloquial register, I would think Examples 2, 3 and 4 mean the same, right?

But in a more formal register, can I say that Example 2 refers to an present real expectation and Example 3 and 4 refer to a past real expectation?

Are there any implicit conditionals implied in Examples 2, 3 and 4? Say, if you were told or given some clue, you would expect such-and-such.. If it is true that there are any, then Examples 2, 3 and 4 refer to irrealis expectations, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got it pretty much right; but I think that the equivalence of 2 and 3 is a matter not of register but of semantics and pragmatics.

Sentence 2 reflects a present conditional;

> You would expect conclusion X if you were presented these premises.

Sentence 3 reflects a past conditional:

> You would have expected conclusion X if you had been presented these premises.

Practically speaking, however, these amount to the same thing: any reasonable person at any time would draw the same inference from the same premises. There is a difference between the two only if something in the context marks the conclusion as historically contingent.

> The conclusion which 18th-century *philosophes* drew is contrary to what you would expect if you were presented these premises today.
>   The conclusion you draw today is contrary to what you would have expected if you had been presented these premises in the 18th century.

Comment: Can you plz explain to me the meaning of 'historical contingency'? I thought it was about evolution. How is it related to your answer? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng *Contingent* means 'happening by chance, not logical necessity', so a 'historically contingent conclusion' is a logical conclusion which depends not just on logic but on circumstances at a particular point in history.

Comment: Come to think of it, you say "you had been presented these premises." But I think it should be "you had been presented **with** these premises." OALD and Macmillan don't say "present" can take double objects. Right? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng *Present, provide, furnish* (and others) may be either mono- or ditransitive; when monotransitive, either what is given or the recipient (but not both!) may be expressed with a preposition phrase.

Comment: Oddly enough, the dictionaries don't have examples of ditransitive usage for these verbs. @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng That then is a defect of the dictionaries; but if you consult Google Books you will many hundreds of such uses from the most estimable authors.